# Two divs FadeIn and FadeOut at same time on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, fade

Here I have simple JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/LKwmW/

If you take a look, you will see when you click the "change" button, the red div will fadeOut completely, and then the blue div will fadeIn. I kind of almost want them to blend, so basically have them fade in and out at the same time, while they still stay on top of each other. Although, if possible, I would prefer the text not to fuse and blend because it will look messy. Maybe the text could fade in after the blend took place?

Here is the HTML:

```
<button id="change">Change </button>

<div id="box1">
    <p> Hello, this is text1 </p>
</div>

<div id="box2">    
    <p> Goodbye, this is text2 </p>

</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#box2').hide()

$('#change').click(function(){
    $('#box1').fadeOut(800, function(){
        $('#box2').fadeIn(800);
    });

});
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the callback, and position the elements on top of each other :

```
$('#box2').hide()

$('#change').click(function(){
    $('#box1').fadeOut(800);
    $('#box2').fadeIn(800);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKwmW/3/)

The text is inside the elements, and it fades with the elements, to avoid that you have to either move the text out of the elements or use CSS transitions to animate just the background colors.

Comment: With my actual program, I can't use position:absolute, because it will screw it up. I'm trying to find an alternative route.

Comment: @BradleyMitchell - If you place the two elements inside a container like I did, it shouldn't matter with regard to document flow etc. There is no other way to this, you either fade just the background, or you fade the elements themselves, and then they would have to be positioned.

Answer (score 1):

[Adeneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751835/2484903) just works fine if you know the size of the divs which are to be toggled. Here a solution when you do not know the height and the children heights can be different from each other but you still want the parent to use the height of the larger child.

This allows comparing two divs for differences without making everything below the comparing divs "jump" when you toggle contents. Main ideas: Use a grid for positioning and use opacity for making the foreground div invisible.

```js
jQuery.fn.visible = function(duration) {
    this.animate({opacity: 1.0}, duration);
};

jQuery.fn.invisible = function(duration) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 0}, duration);
};

var b = false;
$('#change').click(function(){
    if(b){
    $('.child2').visible(1000);
  } else {
    $('.child2').invisible(1000);
  }
  b = !b;
});
```

```css
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.child1 {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.child2 {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="change">Toggle child 1</button>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">child 1</div>
    <div class="child2">child 2</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">child 1<br/>very long content</div>
    <div class="child2">child 2</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">child 1</div>
    <div class="child2">child 2<br/>very long content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `grid` is a really neat way to stack the two children on top of each other, rather than using `position: absolute`. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the effect using `animate` without having multiple `div`

Try something like this

```
$('#box2').hide()

$('#change').click(function(){
   $("#box1").animate({
       backgroundColor:"blue"
  }, 1500 );
});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LKwmW/5/)

Comment: The JSFiddle was just a simple example. My actually program is a lot more complicated, and something like this wouldn't work.